# CoffeeScript class extends - TypeError: Object #<Google> has no method 'perform'

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
class Search
  perform: (text) ->
    query = encodeURIComponent text
    results = ''
    request {uri: @uri + query }, (error, response, body) =>
      if !error? && response.statusCode == 200
        window = jsdom.jsdom(body).createWindow()
        jsdom.jQueryify window, './jquery-1.5.min.js', (window, jquery) =>
          $ = window.$
          jquery(@pattern).each (i, lmn) =>
            link = $(lmn).text() + " - " +  $(lmn).attr('href') 
            if requiresHttp? && /^http/.exec  $(lmn).attr('href')
              results = results + link + "\n"
            else
              results = results + link + "\n"
          @emit 'end', results

sys.inherits(Search, process.EventEmitter)

class Google extends Search
  @uri     = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='
  @pattern = '#ires ol li .r a'
```

When I execute

```
google = new Google
google.perform 'blah'
```

It's returning the error "TypeError: Object #Google has no method 'perform'". Shouldn't the extend provide that method?

**UPDATE**

Shortly after posting I re-factored the code. Here is the working result:

```
{EventEmitter} = require "events"
request        = require 'request'
jsdom          = require 'jsdom'


class Search extends EventEmitter
  constructor: ->
    @linkPrefix   = ''
    @requiresHttp = false
    @uri          = ''
    @pattern      = ''
  perform: (text) ->
    query = encodeURIComponent text
    results = ''
    request {uri: @uri + query }, (error, response, body) =>
      if !error? && response.statusCode == 200
        window = jsdom.jsdom(body).createWindow()
        jsdom.jQueryify window, './jquery-1.5.min.js', (window, jquery) =>
          $ = window.$
          jquery(@pattern).each (i, lmn) =>
            link = $(lmn).text() + " - " + @linkPrefix + $(lmn).attr('href') 
            if @requiresHttp?
              if /^http/.exec  $(lmn).attr('href')
                results = results + link + "\n"
            else
              results = results + link + "\n"
          @emit 'end', results

class Google extends Search
  constructor: ->
    @uri          = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='
    @pattern      = '#ires ol li .r a'
    @requiresHttp = true

class Youtube extends Search
  constructor: ->
    @uri          = 'http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='
    @pattern      = '#search-results h3 a'
    @linkPrefix   = 'http://www.youtube.com'


exports.Google  = Google
exports.Youtube = Youtube
```

Comment: It should work. Perhaps when you inherit from `EventEmitter` it messes with the prototype? You should look at the generated code.

Comment: Btw, one additional change you could make is to write `class exports.Google` and `class exports.Youtube` instead of doing separate `exports.Google = Google` and `exports.Youtube = Youtube` lines. Either works, of course; it's just a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 3):

CD Sandchez's comment is correct. If you cut out the `sys.inherits` line, then `perform` runs.

What you should do instead is use CoffeeScript inheritance all the way:

```
class Search extends process.EventEmitter
```

Comment: Yeah, turns out that was part of the problem. For whatever reason I never received the email notification that someone replied. Thanks, though!